# UTF-8 characters are disappeared after Zend Form render

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I use Zend Framework 2 and have this code in my view script. Name and description are Russian strings:

```
$brand = $form->get('brand');
$id = $brand->get('id');
$name = $brand->get('name');
$type = $brand->get('type');
$description = $brand->get('description');
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($name->getValue()); //correctly dumps russian letters
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($this->formText()->getEncoding()); //UTF-8 (by default)
```

But when I'm trying to render these elements, I have empty input and textarea:

```
<?= $this->formText($name) ?>
<?= $this->formTextarea($description) ?>
```

I've found, that Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper do the following code:

```
$strings[] = sprintf('%s="%s"', $escape($key), $escape($value));
```

after which russian letters disappear. But I still have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: The problem was because of incorrect response headers. Apache sent Content-Type text/html; charset=windows-1251. I resolved the problem by adding "AddDefaultCharset utf-8" to the .htaccess file and all is going OK now.